# How to generate a set of K points evenly spaced in unit cube/sphere of dimension D

Tags: java, math, geometry

I'm trying to generate a set of K points that are evenly spread out **inside** a fixed space, I figured a unit sphere or cube would be easiest.  It was easy enough for 2 dimensions, but it is a lot harder as we go up to arbitrary dimension D, unfortunately.

I think this is done in "quasi Monte Carlo methods" but I've been unable to find a formula, or even a statement as to whether this is a tractable problem. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: What cod ehave you tried so far?

Comment: this isn't a coding question as much as a math question... and even it  was do you usually start coding before you know the solution?

Comment: @justaname: Then why is it labeled with Java? Are you planning on implementing this is java eventually, and wanted answers relating? **Or should it not be labeled as Java as the question does not require a specific language?**

Comment: @Craig yeah, I mean to implement it in java eventually, I tagged it in case there happens to be a library available.

Comment: Are you looking for truly evenly spaced, or statistically uniformly distributed throughout the volume?

Comment: @pjs I'm looking for evenly spaced points, sampling from a uniform would be a poor approximation for small K

Comment: @justaname In that case it's a surprisingly hard problem.  I don't know of a general (K,D) solution, but Gene's suggestion is a common approach to putting points onto the surface of a hyper-cube/sphere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see that calculating the best case is "not trivial" look at the paper [Dense Packings of Equal Spheres in a Cube](http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_11/PDF/v11i1r33.pdf%E2%80%8E) which addresses the subcase of points in a 3D cube: It has exact solutions and "best-known" solutions for only upto 28 points.

It does present an algorithm for finding these optimally spaced configurations, which they call the "Stochastic Billiard" procedure. However I do not know whether this can be adapted to spheres, higher dimensions or larger numbers of points.

It also looks like some aspects of the more general case may be covered in the book [Finite Packing and Covering](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1168653.) - (which I dont have a copy of, so can't verify.)

The 2D case is much more tractable, and you can see further details on wikipedia for [the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square) and [the circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle).

Comment: Ah, excellent, quite a nice paper and actually readable despite my experiences being outside this field.  Not really the case I was hoping for, but it does answer my question.

Comment: @justaname This is why I suggested the motion equations idea.  It sounds comlex but will actually boil out to about a hundred lines of code.  I have used it before.

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you mean by "evenly."  One approach is to position the points randomly and then simulate particle movement in a damping medium with an numerical integrator of Newton's motion equations, where particles and the boundary are mutually repulsive.  This will of course allow any boundary shape at all.

Comment: as for the solution, I think numerical approximation would be required for arbitrary shapes as you mention. But this procedure is rather involved if a closed-form exists for a unit sphere/cube.

Comment: > It depends what you mean by "evenly."
I was wrong in the previous definition, this is better: minimize the maximum-sized hypersphere that encapsulates a single point.

Comment: I just tried modifying my own n-body simulation with a negative G and repulsion at the borders. I think to use this method it must be _very_ carefully tuned, otherwise you will still end up with clumps of particles.

Comment: A good modification on this is to setup your starting values by roughly meshing your area and then putting points in the centers of each mesh element. If you set up the mesh to have roughly the right number of elements, and just randomly add or remove values to get the right count you should get a better starting distribution, which will result in better convergence.

Comment: Also you probably dont want newtons motion, but something with additional drag to force your system to become stable, otherwise it will oscilate forever.

Comment: This is the "damping medium."  It's sufficent to use a linear term in velocity with a negative coefficient. @MichaelAnderson

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the cube as it's easier (I originally said easy, haha). I assume this is what you want (in 3D):

[image]

The number of points on a side is n = floor(K<sup>1/D</sup>). Then the spacing between points is 1 / (n - 1), assuming corners and edges are inclusive. I was going to offer some code for this grid approach, but it's quite ugly and the solution isn't ideal.

Comment: This is better than live tv!

Comment: I'm trying to generate points **inside** the cube, not on the boundaries.. If I understand what you mean.

Comment: @justaname I've included an image. Can you confirm that's what you want?

Comment: @ZongLi It looks about right (and cool) but I can't tell if the points lie only on the surface of the cube or inside the cube from the image.  do they?

Comment: As D becomes larger, the discrepancy between `pow(floor(pow(K,1/D)),D)`  and K becomes proportionately larger. What do you do with the extra points? (e.g if K=26, D=3, `floor(pow(26,1/3)=2` so your grid only contains 8 points, and there are 18 left to distribute)

Comment: Gridded approaches DON'T work well for general K and D.  Even in 2 dimensions, staggered rows and columns that form a "honeycomb" with center points in each hex cell will have better spacing between all pairs of points than you get from a rectangular lattice.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I completely understood your question but here is my go at it.

```
public static List<int[]> getEvenSpacedPoints(int x0, int x1, int y0,
        int y1, int z0, int z1, int samplePerSide) {

    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int xSpacing = (x1 - x0) / samplePerSide;
    int ySpacing = (y1 - y0) / samplePerSide;
    int zSpacing = (z1 - z0) / samplePerSide;

    for (int i = 0; i < samplePerSide; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < samplePerSide; j++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < samplePerSide; w++) {
                int xPoint = xSpacing * i;
                int yPoint = ySpacing * j;
                int zPoint = zSpacing * w;
                int[] point = new int[] { xPoint, yPoint, zPoint };
                list.add(point);
            }
        }

    }
    return list;
}
```

And

```
List<int[]> setOfSamplesFromCube = getEvenSpacedPoints(0, 10, 0, 10, 0,
            10, 5);
    for (int[] point : setOfSamplesFromCube) {
        String ret = "";
        for (int value : point) {
            ret += value + ",";
        }
        System.out.println(ret);
    }
```

Out:

```
0,0,0,
0,0,2,
0,0,4,
0,0,6,
0,0,8,
0,2,0,
0,2,2,
0,2,4,
0,2,6,
0,2,8,
0,4,0,
0,4,2,
0,4,4,
0,4,6,
0,4,8,
0,6,0,
0,6,2,
0,6,4,
0,6,6,
0,6,8,
0,8,0,
0,8,2,
0,8,4,
0,8,6,
0,8,8,
2,0,0,
2,0,2,
2,0,4,
2,0,6,
2,0,8,
2,2,0,
2,2,2,
2,2,4,
2,2,6,
2,2,8,
2,4,0,
2,4,2,
2,4,4,
2,4,6,
2,4,8,
2,6,0,
2,6,2,
2,6,4,
2,6,6,
2,6,8,
2,8,0,
2,8,2,
2,8,4,
2,8,6,
2,8,8,
4,0,0,
4,0,2,
4,0,4,
4,0,6,
4,0,8,
4,2,0,
4,2,2,
4,2,4,
4,2,6,
4,2,8,
4,4,0,
4,4,2,
4,4,4,
4,4,6,
4,4,8,
4,6,0,
4,6,2,
4,6,4,
4,6,6,
4,6,8,
4,8,0,
4,8,2,
4,8,4,
4,8,6,
4,8,8,
6,0,0,
6,0,2,
6,0,4,
6,0,6,
6,0,8,
6,2,0,
6,2,2,
6,2,4,
6,2,6,
6,2,8,
6,4,0,
6,4,2,
6,4,4,
6,4,6,
6,4,8,
6,6,0,
6,6,2,
6,6,4,
6,6,6,
6,6,8,
6,8,0,
6,8,2,
6,8,4,
6,8,6,
6,8,8,
8,0,0,
8,0,2,
8,0,4,
8,0,6,
8,0,8,
8,2,0,
8,2,2,
8,2,4,
8,2,6,
8,2,8,
8,4,0,
8,4,2,
8,4,4,
8,4,6,
8,4,8,
8,6,0,
8,6,2,
8,6,4,
8,6,6,
8,6,8,
8,8,0,
8,8,2,
8,8,4,
8,8,6,
8,8,8,
```

This includes the starting point (start loop on 1 if want to omit) and is "easy" because the cube I passed to it has nice sides that is divisible by 5, otherwise integer division would ruin this, but you can see how it can easily be changed to return a double-list.

I will start trying for a D dimensional case..